# Remove Mysql from homebrew Mac

Tags: mac, mysql, homebrew

When executing brew search mysql brew finds something but when I try to uninstall it it say it can't find it.

```
macbookaaa:sbin aaaa$ brew search mysql 
==> Formulae
automysqlbackup                    mysql++                            mysql-client@5.7                   mysql-sandbox                      mysql@5.6                          mysqltuner
mysql                              mysql-client                       mysql-connector-c++                mysql-search-replace               mysql@5.7
==> Casks
mysql-connector-python             mysql-shell                        mysql-utilities                    mysqlworkbench                     navicat-for-mysql                  sqlpro-for-mysql
mysql-connector-python             mysql-shell                        mysql-utilities                    mysqlworkbench                     navicat-for-mysql                  sqlpro-for-mysql
macbookaaaa:sbin aaaa$ brew remove mysql 
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "mysql".
macbookaaaa:sbin aaaa$ brew remove mysql++
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "mysql++".
macbookaaaa:sbin aaaa$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew search` searches for all available formulas, not installed ones. The remove command is probably failing because you don’t have MySQL installed. Also, it should be “uninstall” not remove.